# How do run `php artisan storage:link` command in cPanel

Tags: php, laravel

I purchase a Flutter app on Codecanyon and I am trying to configure the Laravel admin panel. I am not a Lavarel pro yet so I need help figuring this out. Tried googling solutions but no luck.

Instruction says: link your storage folder to public **Run in terminal or CMD:**

`php artisan storage:link`

After this if you are facing a problem storage link using command please follow the below steps:

`ln -s /home/your_application/storage/app/public /home/your_application/public/storage`

I use VSCode.

I have configured everything else except this one thing.

Comment: Have you tried opening the terminal via cPanel and running the above command?

Comment: @apokryfos Ok thank let me figure out how to do that. I am a novice

Comment: @apokryfos Oh I My cPanel does not have the terminal option. I remember I tired that

Comment: Then https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/guides/linking-storage-folder-without-using-artisan might work

Comment: checking it out

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by activating my terminal in cPanel.

- Most articles I found said it was not possible with shared hosting but I managed to and run script

**Steps**

1. IF you can't see you terminal icon search for "Manage Shell"
2. Enable SSH access
3. Generate SSH Key
4. Go to Manage SSH key and select "Activate"
5. Your Terminal like will now be active
6. Run script

Done